# Convert numpy ndarray to dict but the array has shape ()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In Python 3.7, Numpy: I saved and loaded a dict, using numpy (like I already asked here: [Saving a sequence of 3rd-order Tensors and reading it back without losing array format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811335/saving-a-sequence-of-3rd-order-tensors-and-reading-it-back-without-losing-array) ).

Loading it merges it to one big thing where i cannot get the single values anymore.

I used `np.save('filename', dict)` to save a dictionary like `{(1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 2, (2, 0): 3, (2, 1): 4}` and `loaded_dict = np.load('filename.npy', allow_pickle=True)` to load an object what I need to be a dictionary.

Now just trying to do `loaded_dict[(1, 0)]` does not work. In fact:
`print(loaded_dict.shape)` outputs `()`.

Working example code:

```
import numpy as np

example_dict = {(1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 2, (2, 0): 3, (2, 1): 4}
np.save('filename', example_dict)

loaded_dict = np.load('filename.npy', allow_pickle=True)
print(loaded_dict) # Works just fine, prints out the example dict
print(type(loaded_arrs)) # Outputs <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(loaded_dict.shape) # Outputs ()
print(loaded_dict[(1, 0)]) # Does not work, Error below
```

Output:

```
{(1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 2, (2, 0): 3, (2, 1): 4}
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
()
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I really only need the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4` in that order. Originally I wanted to use the tuples aswell but getting the numbers (in order!) only is enough.

Also: Those numbers are lists in the original. I kept that out of the code to make it more readable. How much of a problem would that be to fix? If you only have a solution for integers, I can use that aswell!

Any help would be very appreciated. I already have an file of 127 KB which took 11 hours to produce, so preferably I would like to make something out of what i already have. If that is impossible or too complicated then I can do a completely fresh start, but only as a last resort.

Comment: Oh yeah. Somehow that did not show up when I searched for it, or I must have overlooked it. Sorry.

Comment: When shape is `()`, you can access the element with an empty tuple, `loaded_dict[()]`.  But `item()` does just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loaded_dict is a numpy.ndarray not a dictionary. You can access the dictionary using .item() method,

```
loaded_dict.item()[(1, 0)]
```

If you want to access all the dictionary values you can use,

```
for key,value in loaded_dict.item().items():
    print(value)
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you very much!